# Setter behavior of python

Tags: python, visual-studio, setter

I am pretty new to python. I came across following strange behavior in my code, due to a typo that I committed.

```
 @property
 def A(self):
     return self._a
 @A.setter
 def A(self,val):
     self._a=val
 @property
 def B(self):
     return self._b
 @A.setter #*********error here******!!
 def B(self,val):
     self._b=val
```

Somewhere in the code:

```
 A=x
 B=y
```

First of all visual studio 2019- python did not catch the bug (or is this really a bug?). Second, the value in `A` and `B` happened to same as the value that I set to `A` (`x` in this example). It did not warn me there is no setter for 'B' when it encountered the line 'B=y'. Is the behavior exhibited here is correct for python?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `property` with getters setters here *to begin with*. It defeats the entire purpose fo `property`. You aren't actually doing anything in your getters or setters, other than getting and setting the value, then *just use a normal attribute*. Anyway, it *looks* like a bug to me, but how is this supposed to be caught by visual studio? And why would it warn you that there is no setter for B? Setters aren't required, that is one of the *features* of `property` descriptors

Comment: There *is* a setter for `B`, the problem is that the *getter* you originally intended for `B` has been overwritten by `A`s. Everything works fine except that accessing `.B` gives you the value of `._a`, even though *assigning to `.B`* sets `._b` as expected.

Comment: @jonrsharpe good catch

Comment: I guess the issue is that this is *completely valid Python code* that just doesn't do what you want it to. Unfortunately, it's also hard for the programmer to spot and debug (e.g. when you look at the backing property `._b` it has the right value, but accessing `.B` gives you the wrong one). A linter can tell you that you probably don't want to redefine `B` (e.g. PyFlakes gives a warning in https://repl.it/repls/OptimisticMoralUnits), but it's not syntactically or otherwise invalid in the language itself.